# Jquery Mobile doesn't change URL when new page loads

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp-classic

On submit my form variables are written to the database and the page changes to the next page BUT the address bar doesn't change. ie it still says mobile2.asp even though the view is mobile3.asp. What am I missing?

```
<head> 
    <title>mysite</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/mycss.css" />
    <script src="include/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="include/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>

<%
dim EN
EN           = xss_Clean(Request.Form("EN"))
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")= "POST" Then
    write_element "EN", EN
    response.redirect "mobile3.asp"
End if
%>
</head> 

<div data-role="content">
        <form action="mobile2.asp" method="post">
        <div id="entries" class="list" data-theme="a">
            <label for="EN" class="select"><h1 class="header">Number required</h1></label>    
    <select name="EN"> 
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="10">10</option> 
       <option value="15">15</option> 
       <option value="20">20</option></select>
        </div>
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" value="submit-value" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false" data-ajax="false">Proceed</button>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the closing *quote* on the redirect?

```
response.redirect "mobile3.asp"
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, the quote is closed.

Comment: Using data-url="/mobile3.asp" on the 'page' updates the URL but using this stops the page specific scripts from loading

Comment: Can't see `data-url="/mobile3.asp"` in your script. ASP won't pick up on that anyhow, you'd need to use jquery to pick it out and process the post. Why not just post to mobile3 in the firstplace?

Comment: `data-url="/mobile3.asp"` is in the 'mobile3.asp' page (the page I'm trying to redirect to) The asp code writes to the var "EN" to my database and then redirects to mobile3.asp but the URL doesn't change. I can force jquery mobile to change the url using `<div id='thirdpage' data-role='page' data-theme='a' data-url='/mobile3.asp'>` but this stops page specific scripts loading. I could post to mobile3 in this instance but mobile3 will need to post back to itself as it's redirect is to an external payment provider.